# ¿como usar switch con un elemento de una cadena en qt?

Tags: string, qt, serialport

lLo que pasa es que estoy comunicando por puerto serial y recibo una cadena (ejemplo a210223), pero para ordenar los datos en la interfaz tengo que identificar la letra inicial y pasarla por un `switch` para identificarlos y mostrarlos. los divido con las siguientes instrucciones:

```
k=serial->readAll();

QString d=k.left(1);

QString b=k.mid(1,3);

QString c=k.mid(4,7);
```

Pero al tratar de usar `switch` con `d` (para el primer dato) me dice que no es un `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suponiendo que `k` sea de tipo `QString` puedes probar algo así:

```
QChar c = k.front();
switch( c.unicode() )
{
  case 'a':
    // ...
}
```

Comment: gracias me funciono, pero otra duda cuando recibo los datos del pic por el serial y los muestro en una interfaz a veces recibe la cadena completa y otras nada y otras solo un elemento de la cadena normalmente el primero y los 2 últimos, me guie con el ejemplo que trae Qt terminal example y en ese si recibe todo pero en el mío no y la configuración y el modo de leer es el mismo, que podría ser???

Comment: @rasenganum asi sin mas datos ni idea... quizás debas formular una pregunta nueva